# Use RAM after GPU memory is not enough

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

Is there any way to use RAM after GPU memory(NVIDIA) is **completely used up** in CUDA?

What I have thought up to now is:

1. Find a way to check if all the thread blocks are used
2. Move the process to RAM

But obiviously this will need alot of syncronization things.

Thank you!

Comment: By RAM you mean global device memory? And, by GPU memory you mean shared memory?

Comment: @srodrb GPU memory means http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu.html and RAM is internal memory of our system

Comment: sorry, your question is a bit confusing for me. I understand what I GPU is, and there are different types of memory on it (shared, registers, global, constant, texture..). I'm looking forward an expert answers the question, looks interesting.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you may be interested in [pinned memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA_Pinned_memory) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the memory on the GPU is not enough you can use the host memory quite easily. What you are looking for is zero-copy memory allocated with `cudaHostAlloc`. Here is the example from the best-practice guide:

```
float *a_h, *a_map; 
... 
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
if (!prop.canMapHostMemory) 
    exit(0); 
cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost); 
cudaHostAlloc(&a_h, nBytes, cudaHostAllocMapped); 
cudaHostGetDevicePointer(&a_map, a_h, 0); 
kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(a_map);
```

However, the performance will be limited by the PCIe bandwitdh (around 6GB/s).

Here is the documentation in the best-practice guide: [Zero-Copy](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/#zero-copy)